# Is it good practice to define variables specific to conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, variables, conditional-statements, naming-conventions

Say I have such a program (python but it is an algorithm question):

```
if boolean == true:
    commonvar = process1()
    var = "foo"
else:
    commonvar = process2()
    var = "bar"
result = intermediate_process (commonvar)
if boolean == true:
     print ("training of {} :{}".format (var, result)
else :
     print ("testing of {} :{}".format (var, result)
```

Is it correct/good design practice to instead modify var in say:

```
if boolean == true:
    commonvar = process1()
    var_true = "foo"
else:
    commonvar = process2()
    var_false = "bar"
result = intermediate_process (commonvar)
if boolean == true:
     print ("training of {} :{}".format (var_true, result)
else :
     print ("testing of {} :{}".format (var_false, result)
```

I'd say one advantage of this is that you can see easily to which "path" in the algorithm belongs the var, and the new variables names might be more relevant (especially practically when adding conditions to preexisting algorithms when the original variable name "var" might have been meaningful and relevant to the original path in the algorithm and might be to the same path in the new algorithm, but might not be meaningful /relevant for the secondary added paths.
On the wrong end, I'd say that it might create bugs more easily, since if you make a reference to one name which has not been defined, the compiler or the program during execution will throw an exception.
That said, that could also be seen as an advantage, since it is easier to match a path to a variable.

What do you think? Indeed naming conventions are usually defined to go together with good design, but I think the question is larger than that, so it is not specially python based (i merely used it because it is readable mostly for anyone understanding programming/english).

Comment: Use `if boolean` instead of `if boolean == True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
print(f"training of foo :{intermediate_process(process1())}" if boolean else
      f"testing of bar :{intermediate_process(process2())}")
```

I think that's a great deal clearer and doesn't require you to remember odd variables defined earlier in your code.  I understand that in more advanced cases, you cannot necessarily reduce it to such a simple one-liner, but without a specific example, it is difficult to discuss what is "best practice". I can't think of one off the top of my head, where it isn't either immediately obvious what to name the placeholder (such as an intermediate sum) or where clarity is actually lost by adding too many variables.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, actually I wrote "intermediate_process" in place of a peculiar code where I had the situation, but you made me aware that I could really use this function usefully, while I discarded this as useless since it would dislocate code more and more.

Comment: You're welcome. ^_^  In my experience, optimising code for readability is not something that has a single always-right answer, and people from different disciplines have different conventions and styles.  But if you think of your code like a narrative, and keep in mind that people can only hold a few variables in their head at the same time, human intuition can get you a long way towards writing accessible code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first example is a better way of going about defining variables. It's easier to debug and since it's set by an if/else clause , it makes more sense for it to be a common variable.

The more the number of variables you declare , the more space is required , since this particular problem can be dealt by with one variable , the first design succeeds. The part about a bug creeping in due to not defining it [ This is bad code principle] Initialize your variable to a value which suits your algorithm  and catch that variable in subsequent code if it doesn't match to either foo or bar which means something else is up with your code.